# how to make cascading dropdown in asp.net mvc by using database Views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008-r2

In my page i have division drop-down in which user selects any division from it and on the selection of this division, i call on change event and in this event i code jquery ajax code and in url call controller getcustomers method in which it query from database views but this ajax method is not working, i also see it in console debugger mode,  i want to populate the customers dropdown required help.

Note: I want to get customers from this database view only.

[Plz see the image of database view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etExA.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        function DivisionChanged(item) {

            //$("#dvn_code").change(function () {$('#dvn_code')
            var select_division = $(item).val();
            $("#customers").empty();

            debugger;
            $.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomers")',
                type: 'POST',
                @*url: '@Url.Action("GetStates")'*@ // we are calling json method
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $(this).val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    customers.append($('<option/>', { value: -1, text: 'Select customers' }));
                    $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                        customers.append($('<option/>', { value: item.id, text: item }));

                    });

                }

            });
            return false;
        }
        </script>
```

///// controller code

```
public JsonResult GetCustomers(int id)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBContext"].ConnectionString;
            List<V_CustomerForDropDown> customers = new List<V_CustomerForDropDown>();
            String query = "SELECT cst_Name FROM PT.V_CustomerForDropDown where dvn_code==id";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    V_CustomerForDropDown c = new V_CustomerForDropDown();
                    c.cst_Name = rdr["cst_Name"].ToString();
                    customers.Add(c);

                }
               // con.Close();
                return this.Json(customers);
            }
        }
```

Updated(Now this is the problem):
I pass the data in json format to view from controller and it also pass the data but in view how to populate it in drop down list

// controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCustomers(string id)
        {
            var customers = (from a in db.V_CustomerForDropDown.Where(c => c.dvn_code == id) select new { a.cst_Name, a.cst_Code }).ToList();

            return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

//index.chtml

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                                        <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="customers"  multiple title="Multiple Select" data-live-search="true" data-menu-style="dropdown-blue">
                                            </select>
```

// javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function DivisionChanged(item) {
             var select_division = $(item).val();

        $.ajax({

            url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomers")',// we are calling json method
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: select_division },
            success: function (customers) {
                debugger;
                $.each(customers, function (i, cust) {
                    $("#customers").append('<option value>' + cust.cst_Name +  '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: String query = String.Format("SELECT cst_Name FROM PT.V_CustomerForDropDown where dvn_code=={0}",id)

Comment: _not working_ is not useful.What is not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I pass the data in json format to view from controller and it also pass the data but in view how to populate it in drop down list, please see my updated problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data: { 'id':  select_division }
```

Decorate Action method with `[HttpPost]`

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetCustomers(int id)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBContext"].ConnectionString;
            List<V_CustomerForDropDown> customers = new List<V_CustomerForDropDown>();
            String query = "SELECT cst_Name FROM PT.V_CustomerForDropDown where dvn_code==id";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    V_CustomerForDropDown c = new V_CustomerForDropDown();
                    c.cst_Name = rdr["cst_Name"].ToString();
                    customers.Add(c);

                }
               // con.Close();
                return this.Json(customers);
            }
        }
```

Change your query

```
String query = "SELECT cst_Name FROM PT.V_CustomerForDropDown where dvn_code="+ id;
```

After change all these put a debug on Action method and check if it'll hit or not if yes than put a debug on success function of ajax and check data is filling as per your expactations

**UPDATE**

Make an extension method to tackle null string value in controller.
    public static class Extensions
    {

```
    public static string EmptyIfNull(this object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return "";
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
c.cst_Name = rdr["cst_Name"].EmptyIfNull();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help,  i want to know that in 
c.cst_Name = rdr["cst_Name"].ToString(); // c.cst_Name have null value
 Can you plz tell how to tackle it in controller

Comment: Plz tell me how to populate the drop down list in ajax call when i return the customers in json format from the controller

Comment: It would be a new question post it to SO again as it's completely unrelated to this question and you want a reference than pleae follow [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/32bcb2/different-ways-for-populating-dropdownlist-in-mvc/) or [this](http://tutorial.techaltum.com/dropdown-binding-using-ajax-in-mvc.html) link there are a lot good example and if you find my answer is useful please marked it as answer above

Comment: If you want to see [how to marked as answer on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: When I debug in console of browser it shows the values comes from controller here  $("#show_customers").append("<option>" + cust.cst_Code + ' " - " ' + cust.cst_Name + "</option>");
but not append in my view drop down, thanks in advance

Comment: first make sure you have `show_customers` id of selectlist is it right? second you are iterating through a json is json is getting all values of customer? if not of above than paste your ajax request here and selectlist html so i can figure out

Comment: yes the id of selectlist is right and json is getting all values of the customer, btw the code is::
   <script type="text/javascript"> function DivisionChanged(item) {var select_division = $(item).val();
 $.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomers")',// we are calling json method
type: 'POST',  dataType: 'json', data: { id: select_division },success: function (customers) {debugger;$.each(customers, function (index, cust) {$("#show_customers").append("<option>" + cust.cst_Code + ' " - " ' + cust.cst_Name + "</option>"); });}}); return false; }</script>  //html

Comment: <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="show_customers"  multiple title="Multiple Select" data-live-search="true" data-menu-style="dropdown-blue">
                                              </select>

Comment: what is in response of `customers` ? what json it return ?

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCustomers(string id)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled =false;
            var customers = (from a in db.V_CustomerForDropDown.Where(c => c.dvn_code == id) select new { a.cst_Code, a.cst_Name }).ToList();
            
            return Json(customers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }